# Calling a Method that has Generic Parameters

Tags: java, generics, methods, call

I am trying to understand some source code. **How do I call this method in main?**

```
public void introSort(T[] array, int max_depth)
    {
        System.out.println(array.length);
    }
```

I simply want to return the length of the given array in my main method. If this is any help, the method is in a class with this declaration:

```
public class IntroSort<T extends Comparable<T>> extends AbstractSort<T> {
```

[I understand that this is of generic type, but my understanding of that concept in Java is too minimal for me to answer my questions.]

Comment: What does this have to do with generics? It's an array. Use its `length` field.

Comment: Ok, but how do you declare the array of that type then, so I can call that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the array element is the type variable `T` of the class `IntroSort`. This is an example for an instance of `IntroSort` with the type parameter set as `Integer`:

```
Integer[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
IntroSort<Integer> obj = new IntroSort<>();
obj.introSort(array, 1);
```

The compiler would match `T` with `Integer` based on the declaration of `IntroSort`, which also means that the array must be of type `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

The T is just referring back to the T in your class specification.

If you have an instance of IntroSort, just call the method on it with the same type of array as you instantiated the class with.